# BLOB datatype in NAV

Tags: blob, navision

I have a requirement from the customer that he wants to store a huge text in a field in NAV. The data type text supports only 250 characters in a table. I am not sure how to use BLOB data type. Could you please guide me in this regard?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/blob-data-type) is the description of the Blob datatype.

The main problem with it is that you can’t just throw the field to the page. You need to declare a variable of text type, make it a source of the field on a page and read the value of the blob into that variable `OnAfterGetRecord`.

If you want to write to the blob field you need to write the content of the mentioned text variable to blob fiel `OnValidate` of the field on the page.

This approach has it’s limitations. You can’t filter or search on such field.